# Which is better ORM (Apache Cayenne) , JDBC or SpringJDBC?

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc, apache-cayenne

I am Working on multiple database like MSSQL server and PostgreSQL with heavy transactions and complex queries. I have searched that simple jdbc is more faster then ORM. I was thinking of using ORM because I do not want to write different query for different database for same work, and also for standardized my dao layer. I am mapping my database tables without using foreign keys and for ORM like apache cayenne I have to map tables with foreign key constraint, so I can use my Joins or any other multiple table operations. Is it good to use and ORM or simple jdbc is fine.

Answer (score 0):

From your problem dscription, you already have an understanding of the tradeoffs involved. So this is really a decision that you need to make for yourself based on those tradeoffs.

My only advice here will be to take a second look at performance requirements. While ORM does introduce an overhead of creating, storing and managing  objects, in all but a few cases, you can safely ignore this overhead for the sake of a better abstraction. Also when working with JDBC very often you end up writing your own code to convert ResultSet to objects, which will encounter its own overhead. So you may not end up with faster code, while forfeiting all the benefits of a clean object model and a framework that manages it.

So my own preference is to go with a better abstraction (ORM in this case), and then use the framework tools for optimizing the performance. E.g. to speed up processing of large ResultSets Cayenne [provides a few techniques](http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/4.0/cayenne-guide/performance-tuning.html): result iterators, DataRow queries, paginated queries, etc.

On the other hand I would use JDBC or something like [MyBatis](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/) when it is not possible to cleanly model your data as entities. E.g. when there are no natural relationships, all access happens via stored procedures, etc. Doesn't seem like your case though.